# how to get the current list using jquery UI?

Tags: jquery-ui, javascript

I am using the following code:

html:

```
<ul id = "list1" class="connect">
<li>item1</li>
<li>item2</li>
</ul>


<ul id = "list2" class="connect">
<li>item1</li>
<li>item2</li>
</ul>
```

jquery:

```
$("#list1, #list2").sortable({
  revert: true,
  connectWith:".connect",
  helper: "clone"
})
```

so my question is: is it possible to know if we are doing a sort in the first list?.

I am trying to use a function only when list1 changes or should we do a sort in the list1,  and to use other function when the item changes from a list to other.

I hope that is clear.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what you want to do.  Do you want a function called at some event?  If so, what even should trigger that function call?

Comment: yes, the problem is that I don't know what event to use when the list1 changed with the its items, I know that I can use out or receive when the item change from a list to another, but what event should I used when the items are from the same list, something like to move item1 to position item2 in the list1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the this object, which will tell you which object called the method:

```
$("#list1, #list2").sortable({start: function () {
   console.log($(this).attr("id"));            
}});​
```

Sample fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2rY3j/4/